# XMLHttpRequest.open POST request with parameters asp.net

Tags: javascript, ajax, xml, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to use a javascript XMLHttpRequest object to post back to my action method.

currently I have the following:

```
xmlhttp.open('POST', '../Employees1/HandleFileUpload', true);
```

with my action method taking no parameters

```
public PartialViewResult HandleFileUpload() {

}
```

how do I change the `.open` method if I want my action method to take one argument:

```
public PartialViewResult HandleFileUpload(int year) {

}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest

Comment: Are you sure its the `.open` and not the `.send` that has to change?

Comment: @Musa no I'm not, is it the .send?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did the following and it worked:

```
xmlhttp.open('POST', '../Employees1/HandleFileUpload?year=2014', true);
```

Comment: Your code will work as GET and not as POST
`xmlhttp.open('POST', '../Employees1/HandleFileUpload', true); 
xmlhttp.send("year=2014&otherparam=otherdata")` - this will send data as post request

Comment: @genichm thank you for sharing the correct method! I'll change it in my code.